# SSRS how to get a running total of inventory amounts IN and OUT from START DATE to END DATE?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

i have a stored proc returning inventory amounts between a start and end date.

the QTY field shows on-hand inventory adjustments by date, either IN or OUT.

i have a "run balance" field that needs to show the total QTY each day. if the InOut field is 0, it's QTY in. if it's a 1, its QTY out. the values reflected in In and Out are coded that way.

EXAMPLE. if i start on 4/1/14 with 5216. then 1061 of product is made on 4/1/14 i need the run balance to take 5216 and add 1061 on the next line. the next line should read 6277 instead of 1061. then if some is shipped, take 6277 and subtract, and so on.

i tried the running value on QTY, but it just repeats the QTY. doesn't calculate anything.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!QTY.Value,Sum,"Details")
```

i tried to post an image of my report preview, but i don't have the reputation ;-)

any help would be MUCH appreciated.

EDIT: OK, i tried this code block:

```
= Switch(RunningValue(Iif(Fields!InOut.Value = 0, Fields!QTY.Value,0),Sum,"Details"), 
RunningValue(Iif(Fields!InOut.Value = "1", Fields!RunBalance.Value -   Fields!QTY.Value,0),Sum,"Details"))
```

and i am getting a 0 on the sum fields, and #Error on the subtraction fields. but, i think this is more the direction i need to go (i hope)....but i am still not getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to look at here.

First, you specify the Scope of `"Details"` in your `RunningValue` expression... By default this group will have no grouping value, i.e. each row in the dataset will be in its own group. Which means the `RunningValue` will only ever be applied to one row only. Change the Scope to `"MyDataset"` or `Nothing`, whatever is appropriate.

Secondly, you need to consider how the `InOut` field affects the `RunningValue`.

I have created a simple Dataset:

[image]

And a simple table:

[image]

The `Balance` expression is:

```
=RunningValue(IIf(Fields!InOut.Value = 0, Fields!QTY.Value, Fields!QTY.Value * -1)
  , Sum
  , Nothing)
```

You can see this changes the Scope from your original statement, and also applies a multiplier to `QTY` based on `InOut`.

Works OK for my sample data:

[image]

Comment: OK, thank you, this is definitely helping. its still not subtracting for me, it's adding everything. i have IN and OUT and separate fields. not sure if that is affecting. however, its in the right direction.

once i added your code, i no longer needed "Details" ... so do i need to apply both of your scenarios, or just one?

Comment: i'm also getting this error:

[rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘RunBalance1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.

Comment: This worked for me doing it the opposite:

=RunningValue(IIf(Fields!InOut.Value = 1, Fields!QTY.Value * -1, Fields!QTY.Value), Sum, Nothing)

when i did it with a zero check on InOut it only added. but checking on the 1 worked perfectly. 

thank you for your help!